# Kubuntu: my bluetooth audio sync is very bad

Tags: sound, kubuntu, bluetooth

I have installed kubuntu in my laptop but the bluetooth audio sync is very bad it delays several seconds around 3-4.

FYI: The normal audio in my laptop is working as expected.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks